# Failed to generate a user instance of SQL server due to failure in starting the process for the user instance

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have to create database on visual studio 2010 but unfortunately "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL server due to failure in starting the process for the user instance" this type of error display

Deleting the folder C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data also worked for me in Windows 7. Restart the computer after deleting the folder

plz help me...:)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the SQL Server service to use your local or system account and restart the service.  This worked for me the first time.